# Bluetooth audio stops working days/weeks later

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

Freshly paired BT headphones work fine (with the general win7 audio-quality bugs included).

But if I try to reconnect the headphones weeks later, although connection is successful, the audio-sink simply doesn't work at all: Windows claims that headphones are still disconnected though headphones clearly connected, and I can actually change their settings in the properties.

After twiddling with the setting for a long time, I sometimes manage to trigger something unknown, and the Windows' "Installing drivers" dialog comes up and tells me that the Windows installs the BT audio subsystem *again*. But the audio still doesn't work and "Sound" dialog's "Playback" tab still shows the headphones as "disconnected".

To make it work again, I have to delete the pairing, and re-pair again. (And repeat configuration of the headphones again - to minimize the usual Win7 BT audio glitches.)

Is there any way to avoid the hustle? Or BT audio is really truly broken on the Win7?

Comment: BTW, I have seen this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/186552/windows-7-bluetooth-stereo-audio-a2dp-only-works-when-freshly-paired) but it doesn't really have any definitive answer and the suggestions do not work for me.

Comment: Please go into more detail beyond just "do not work for me"

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure how I can explain this - `"Sound" dialog's "Playback" tab still shows the headphones as "disconnected".` - in more details.

Comment: So specify hardware details.